# What game is this Steam background from?

Tags: steam, game-identification

I was sent a [link to a Steam profile background](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywUlj3Hz8JQD_k62zmnzAEbeQUdVBitsTVCj831QvuYDe0T1IhlssIGiXk_xFgubefhNmUyJAfGWKJaXaJtpArpXX5j6ZZlBI7lpLpfKw7qvNDALepsZyYwSncA) and I want to buy the background, but I can't for the life of me figure out what game it's from.

If anybody knows the game it's from and/or has a direct link that would be great.

[image: Sexy lady Steam profile background]

Answer (score 11):

It's [Ridika The Temptress](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/207230-Ridika%20The%20Temptress%20(Profile%20Background)) from ArcheBlade.

Comment: $5 for a background ? Wow.

Comment: @Ealhad What do you think about hundreds for a knife?

Comment: Well, I'd gladly sell it if I had one ^^

Comment: @Ealhad ArcheBlade is a free to play game, which means that players get one trading card per $9 or so spent on in-game purchases. That means you need to spend over $70 to get the eight cards necessary to complete a set and get a random profile background. If ArcheBlade is like most F2P games then then vast majority of players won't have spent anywhere near this, meaning there's a lot of potential interest and not much supply. Add in the sex appeal factor and it's not too hard to see why it might sell for so much.

Comment: @Ealhad buy the card on the marked 0.17$ per card maybe you're lucky and get the background

Comment: @Nitro.de I don't really feel like actually spending money for that kind of things. I like trading cards, though.

Comment: @Ealhad then take a look into the forum and try to trade them